# How to change image and link with data values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I start learn Javascript and I need your help.
I have big image and under big image there are 3 thumbnails. If user click second thumbnail, big image has to changes to second data-bigimage.
And swipebox link has to change to second data-original image. The same for other images.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="profile-gallery">
<div class="profile-gallery_top js-bigImg">
    <a href="img/bigImg1.jpg" class="swipebox">
        <img class="profile-bigImage" src="img/bigImg.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
<ul class="profile-thumbs">
    <li><img src="img/imgThmubs1.jpg" data-bigimage="img/bigImg1.jpg" data-original="img/origImg1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="img/imgThmubs2.jpg" data-bigimage="img/bigImg2.jpg" data-original="img/origImg2.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="img/imgThmubs3.jpg" data-bigimage="img/bigImg3.jpg" data-original="img/origImg3.jpg" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks you guys solutions it works! But in swipebox gallery there is a single image, how can I insert all images to swipebox array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('.profile-thumbs li').click(function(){
        var imageurl = $(this).children('img').data('bigimage');
        var imageorig = $(this).children('img').data('original');

        $('.profile-bigImage').attr("src", imageurl);
        $('.swipebox').attr("href", imageorig);
    });
});
```

$(this) is always the clicked element in a click function matching the selector.

Comment: Thanks you for good solution it works! But in swipebox there is a single image, how can I insert all images to swipebox array?

Comment: so you need every three image into the swipe box wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

This may do the stuff, try this:

```
$(".profile-thumbs li img").click(function() {
    var bigImg = $(this).data("bigimage"),
        original = $(this).data("original");
    $(".swipebox").attr("href", original);
    $(".profile-bigImage").attr("src", bigImg);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

look at the below example using jQuery.

```
`$(this)` will refer the image clicked.
```

so `$(this).attr('src')` will be the source of the image which we click.
assign it to the image which is having `class` `profile-bigImage`

```js
$('img').click(function(){
var imgsrc=$(this).attr('src');
  $('.profile-bigImage').attr('src',imgsrc);


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-gallery">
<div class="profile-gallery_top js-bigImg">
    <a href="img/bigImg1.jpg" class="swipebox">
        <img class="profile-bigImage" src="img/bigImg.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
<ul class="profile-thumbs">
    <li><img src="img/imgThmubs1.jpg" data-bigimage="img/bigImg1.jpg" data-original="img/origImg1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="img/imgThmubs2.jpg" data-bigimage="img/bigImg2.jpg" data-original="img/origImg2.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="img/imgThmubs3.jpg" data-bigimage="img/bigImg3.jpg" data-original="img/origImg3.jpg" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that, it should work

```
$(document).on('click','.profile-thumbs img', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $('.profile-gallery-top a').attr('href', $(this).data('original'));
    $('.profile-gallery-top img').attr('src', $(this).data('bigimage'));
});
```